# R/igraph: adjusting meeting point of edges on a vertex

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am trying to use igraph to plot pedogree [image: pedigree]. I would like to have the edges met together (right figure) instead of spaced apart (left figure) in the default setting.

I can't find the correct argument in igraph manual to set the edge positions. Anyone knows?

Here are the R scripts used to generate the left figure.

```
    library(igraph)
    ped <- data.frame(id=1:3, p1=c(0,0,1), p2=c(0,0,2), gen=c(0,0,1))
    rel <- matrix(c(1,2,3,3), ncol=2)
    ped.graph <- graph.data.frame(rel, directed=F, ped)
    pos <- matrix(c(1,2,1.5,2,2,1), ncol=2)
    plot(ped.graph, rescale=T, layout=pos, vertex.size=50)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example? What have you already tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: have a look here for how to ask questions on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the R scripts. Hope that helps.